# Rotate a Bitmap around an angle and also move it along a Pathmeasure

Tags: java, android, path, bitmap, rotation

```
Matrix mxTransform = new Matrix();
PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(pathMoveAlong, false);
//walkedLength= moved distance
pm.getMatrix(walkedLength, mxTransform,PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG);
pm.getPosTan(walkedLength, pos, tan);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmImage, mxTransform, posPaint);
```

In my Application i want to rotate an arrow around a angle from Sensor-data and also move it along a `Path` (pathMoveAlong). Now I want to rotate the arrow/Bitmap on his actual position.

I tried:

```
mxTransform.setRotate(measuredAngle,pos[0],pos[1]);
```

But the Bitmap does not rotate around the expected position.

Comment: Does `pm.getMatrix()` return a value, or does it use an output parameter?

Comment: it writes the movement transformation matrix from my PathMeasure in my matrix mxTransform

Comment: Try sticking a breakpoint right before your draw to make sure that your `Matrix` contains the right angle